# How should I handle asynchronous processes that occur after API calls in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, amazon-kinesis, aws-dms

I'm designing the backend for a website that uses API Gateway and Lambda to handle API requests, many of which target a MySQL DB on RDS. Some processes need to happen asynchronously but I'm debating which is best practice or cleaner.

In the given scenario, every time a user creates a new row in a certain table, let's say an email also needs to be sent asynchronously. There are many other scenarios similar to this but this will set precedent.

Option 1: In the lambda that handles the API request, first write to the MySQL instance to add the new row. When the response from MySQL comes back successful, write to something like SQS which will later be read from another lambda that sends an email. When the response from SQS is successful that the record was added to the queue, send a 201 response saying the REST API call was successful.

Option 2: In the lambda that handles the API request, write to the MySQL instance to add the new row. When the response from the MySQL comes back successful, send a 201 response saying the REST API call was successful. Then set up a DMS (data migration service) task that runs indefinitely to send database modification binlogs to a kinesis stream which will trigger a lambda that will handle all DB changes, read the change as a new row in a certain table, and send an email.

Option 1:

- less infrastructure
- more direct tracking of logic from an API call
- 1 extra http call (to sqs) delaying response times for an api for a web page

Option 2:

- more infrastructure (dms task, replication instance)
- scaling out shards may mean loss of ordering when processes binlog events if ordering is a requirement (it is)

  - side question: Are you able to choose hash key for kinesis for dms tasks from mysql?
- a single codebase for reacting to all modifications in the DB may actually make following logic in code simpler

Is this the tradeoff or am I missing something? What is best practice in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 in my view seems most logical, but I would **replace SQS and second lambda with SNS**. So, modified option 1 could be:

> Option 1: In the lambda that handles the API request, first write to the MySQL instance to add the new row. When the response from MySQL comes back successful, **publish confirmation message to SNS that sends an email**. When the response from **SNS** is successful send a 201 response saying the REST API call was successful.

This should be faster, cheaper and easier to implement then using SQS and second lambda for sending email.